# How to configure multiple target groups and listeners aws with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, listener, target, aws-application-load-balancer

my plan
alb-->fe-server-->alb-->be-server
Frontend ihave on angular and in main.js baseurl on ABL
Backend maven working on port 8080
two listeners 80 and 8080 ports

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_http_fe" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb_fe_be.arn
  port = 80
  ...
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule_fe" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.listener_http_fe.arn
  priority = 100
  action {
  type = "forward"
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group_fe.arn
 }
  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["*"]
    }
 ...

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_http_be" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb_fe_be.arn
  port = 8080
  protocol = "HTTP"
 ...
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule_be" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.listener_http_be.arn
  priority = 101
```

...

two target groups

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group_fe" {
  name = 12 
  port = 80    
  protocol = "HTTP"
 ...
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group_be" {
  name = 11 
  port = 8080    #port to be-server(8080)
  ...
```

How i need to configure because working only fe-server or be-server separately but not together with ALB?

Comment: What exactly do mean by "working only fe-server or be-server separately but not together with ALB"?

Comment: I have a similar issue - two different alb_lb_listener resources pointing to two different aws_lb_target_group resources configured for the same NLB, and each time I run terraform it simply swaps between the two, never creates both.

Comment: Found the answer - I don't like it, but seems the only way to add multiple listeners is to set your configuration for each listener and each target group in a variable file and use a single aws_lb_listener object with a for_each loop to go through each item in your config.  This is explained in this document here:  https://medium.com/@sahityamaruvada/setting-up-aws-network-load-balancer-with-terraform-0-12-b87e75992949